# Android: How to control for loop using button clicks(Eg: Just as who wants to be a millionaire app)

Tags: android, for-loop, foreach

Please am currently working on a quiz app tailored down to exam preparation.
I am stuck with submitting question.
Please here is my code.
I want my question to change same as who wants to be a millionaire app in which it brings first set of question and after answer is given for it, a new question all together appears.
Please how can I go about it.

```
    continued = "Continue";
    databaseHelper = new ExamDbHandler(ExamGround.this);
    db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    scores = 0;
    tvAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    tvexplain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.explain);
    score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
    scres = score.getText().toString();
    examTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.examTitle);
    bOption1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option1);
    bOption2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option2);
    bOption3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option3);
    bOption4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.option4);
    confirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirm);
    proceed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.proceedto);
    ahint = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.allhint);
    bOption1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
    bOption2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
    bOption3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
    bOption4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
    confirm.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
    proceed.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
            // getData() gets all questions from my sqlite database
    SQLView sv = databaseHelper.getData();
```

I want the loop to start from here, (I may be wrong though!)

```
    answer = sv.getAnswer().toString();
    question = sv.getQuestion();
    explain = sv.getExplanation().toString();
    option1 = sv.getOption1();
    option2 = sv.getOption2();
    option3 = sv.getOption3();
    option4 = sv.getOption4();

    tvQuestion.setText(question);
    bOption1.setText(option1);
    bOption2.setText(option2);
    bOption3.setText(option3);
    bOption4.setText(option4);

    actual = bOption1.getText().toString();
    actual2 = bOption2.getText().toString();
    actual3 = bOption3.getText().toString();
    actual4 = bOption4.getText().toString();
    soption1 = 0;
    soption2 = 0;
    soption3 = 0;
    soption4 = 0;
    bOption1.setOnClickListener(ExamGround.this);
    bOption2.setOnClickListener(this);
    bOption3.setOnClickListener(this);
    bOption4.setOnClickListener(this);
    confirm.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View V) {
    switch (V.getId()) {
    case R.id.option1:
        soption1 = 1;
        soption2 = 0;
        soption3 = 0;
        soption4 = 0;
        bOption1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCCFFCC"));
        bOption2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
        bOption3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
        bOption4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
        break;
    case R.id.option2:
        soption1 = 0;
        soption2 = 1;
        soption3 = 0;
        soption4 = 0;
        bOption1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
        bOption2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCCFFCC"));
        bOption3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
        bOption4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
        break;
    case R.id.option3:
        soption1 = 0;
        soption2 = 0;
        soption3 = 1;
        soption4 = 0;
        bOption1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
        bOption2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
        bOption3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCCFFCC"));
        bOption4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
        break;
    case R.id.option4:
        soption1 = 0;
        soption2 = 0;
        soption3 = 0;
        soption4 = 1;
        bOption1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
        bOption2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
        bOption3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#33FF33FF"));
        bOption4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCCFFCC"));
        break;
    case R.id.confirm:
        tvexplain.setText(explain);
        ahint.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        proceed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        proceed.setText(continued);
        confirm.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        if(actual.equals(answer)){
            bOption1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF66FF66"));
                if(soption1 == 1){
                    scores++;
                }
            }
        if(actual2.equals(answer)){
                bOption2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF66FF66"));
                if(soption2 == 1){
                    scores++;
                }
            }
        if(actual3.equals(answer)){
                bOption3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF66FF66"));
                if(soption3 == 1){
                    scores++;
                }
            }
        if(actual4.equals(answer)){
                bOption4.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF66FF66"));
                if(soption4 == 1){
                    scores++;
                }
            }
        break;
    case R.id.proceedto:
        //In here I want the loop to read next question
        break;
    }
```

Please I don't know if this question have been asked before, I tried searching but for over 2 days now, I haven't gotten any clue.
Please all answers are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: I dont think you need a loop for that, just call a method to clear the selected option and reload information from a new question (reading from DB?).

Comment: Yeah, a loop isn't the right method here.  Instead you want to use a more MVC approach, load the next question and inform the views to refresh based on new data.  Also, your code has way too much copy paste in it, you need to break stuff down into functions and data structures more-  you'd be getting a C at best for this effort.

Comment: Thanks for these response but please, how can I get the questions randomly and also clearing the activity as well as setting it again.